# The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have 3 tables in SQL Server:

**CountriesTbl**:

```
CountryID int output,
CountryName nvarchar (50),
Nots nvarchar (Max),
ModifiedBy nvarchar (30)
```

**CitiesTbl**:

```
CityID int output,
CityName nvarchar (50),
CountryID int,
Nots nvarchar (Max),
ModifiedBy nvarchar (30)
```

**CustomersTbl**:

```
CustomerID int output,
CustomerName nvarchar (50),
CustomerPhoto image,
CustomerEmail nvarchar(Max),
CustomerPhone1 nvarchar(12),
CustomerPhone2 nvarchar(12),
CustomerAddress nvarchar(Max),
CustomerFax nvarchar(12),
CustomerStatus bit,
CountryID int,
CityID int,
Notes nvarchar (Max),
ModifiedBy nvarchar (30)
```

[image]

The update stored procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Update_Customer_WithOutPic]
    @CustomerID int,
    @CustomerName nvarchar (50),
    @CustomerEmail nvarchar(Max),
    @CustomerPhone1 nvarchar(12),
    @CustomerPhone2 nvarchar(12),
    @CustomerAddress nvarchar(Max),
    @CustomerFax nvarchar(12),
    @CustomerStatus bit,
    @CountryID int,
    @CityID int,
    @Notes nvarchar (Max),
    @ModifiedBy nvarchar (30)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE CustomersTbl 
    SET CustomerName = @CustomerName,
        CustomerEmail = @CustomerEmail,
        CustomerPhone1 = @CustomerPhone1,
        CustomerPhone2 = @CustomerPhone2,
        CustomerAddress = @CustomerAddress,
        CustomerFax = @CustomerFax,
        CustomerStatus = @CustomerStatus,
        CountryID = @CountryID,
        CityID = @CityID,
        Notes = @Notes,
        ModifiedDate = GETDATE(),
        ModifiedBy = @ModifiedBy
    WHERE
        CustomerID = @CustomerID
END
```

In VB, I have 2 classes: data layer and business layer.

Data layer - update code:

```
Friend Function Update_Customer_WithOutPic(ByVal CustomerID As String, ByVal CustomerName As String, ByVal CustomerEmail As String, ByVal CustomerPhone1 As String, ByVal CustomerPhone2 As String, ByVal CustomerAddress As String, ByVal CustomerFax As String, ByVal CustomerStatus As Boolean, ByVal CountryID As Integer, ByVal CityID As Integer, ByVal Notes As String, ByVal ModifiedBy As String) As String
            Dim retval As String
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Update_Customer_WithOutPic")
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", CustomerID)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", CustomerName)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerEmail", CustomerEmail)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerPhone1", CustomerPhone1)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerPhone2", CustomerPhone2)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerAddress", CustomerAddress)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerFax", CustomerFax)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerStatus", CustomerStatus)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryID", CountryID)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityID", CityID)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", Notes)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifiedBy", ModifiedBy)

            retval = dm.executeNonQuery(cmd)

            Return retval
        End Function
```

Business layer:

```
  Public Function Update_Customer_WithOutPic(ByVal CustomerID As String, ByVal CustomerName As String, ByVal CustomerEmail As String, ByVal CustomerPhone1 As String, ByVal CustomerPhone2 As String, ByVal CustomerAddress As String, ByVal CustomerFax As String, ByVal CustomerStatus As Boolean, ByVal CountryID As Integer, ByVal CityID As Integer, ByVal Notes As String, ByVal ModifiedBy As String) As String
            Dim retval As String
            retval = p.Update_Customer_WithOutPic(CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerEmail, CustomerPhone1, CustomerPhone2, CustomerAddress, CustomerFax, CustomerStatus, CountryID, CityID, Notes, ModifiedBy)
            Return retval
        End Function
```

Now the update button code:

```
Dim retval As String = p.Update_Customer_WithOutPic(txtCustomerCode.Text, txtCustomerName.Text, txtCustomerEmail.Text, txtCustomerPhone1.Text, txtCustomerPhone2.Text, txtCustomerAddress.Text, txtCustomerFax.Text, CheckBox2.Checked, ComboCustomerCountry.SelectedValue, ComboCustomerCity.SelectedValue, txtCustomernote.Text, FrmMain.LblUserID.Text)
```

I get this error:

> The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_CustomersTbl_CountriesTbl". The conflict occurred in database "AlwaleedSSSystem", table "dbo.CountriesTbl", column 'CountryID'.

Comment: Sounds like you are updating the customer table with a non existing countryId

Comment: Is `CustomersTbl.CustomerStatus` being connected to `CountriesTbl.CountryID` just an artifact of the diagram?

Comment: CustomersTbl.CountryID Connected to CountriesTbl.CountryID

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have a foreign key constraint from your customer table pointing at your countries table and the countryId you are selecting in the country combo box does not exist in the country table. Make sure you are loading your country ids from the same table your customer table is referencing.

You should do some reading regarding constraints and database referential integrity.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=sql.105).aspx